# How to check value exist before inserting a data

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to ask about checking a value in the database: when the value exist it will echo an alert message and when not it will do an insert function.

I have try a code like this but it seems not work.

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");
if(isset($_POST['table-bordered'])){
 $array=json_decode($_POST['table-bordered'],true);
 foreach($array as $item) {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE no_pol='".$item['no_pol']."',date='".$item['date']."',time='".$item['time']."'";
 $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($query)> 0)
 {
  echo "Data sudah pernah di Input..!!";
 }
 else{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO wjm (sloc,kode,nama,no_pol,id,date,time,netto,unit,uses,payroll) VALUES ('".$item['sloc']."', '".$item['kode']."', '".$item['nama']."', '".$item['no_pol']."', '".$item['id']."', '".$item['date']."', '".$item['time']."', '".$item['netto']."', '".$item['Unit']."', '".$item['uses']."', '".$item['payroll']."')";
        if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
     echo "Records inserted successfully.";
  } else{
     echo "Records inserted failed ";
  }
 }
}
}
?>
```

I want to check the value in my select function. when it exist in my table in will echo an alert in the page. I have try whit `select count` too but it not working

Comment: Conditions in query are grouped with `AND`/`OR` and not with commas.

Comment: let me try to change it

Comment: nice it working..
btw. why the alert i get to much?

Comment: Bcoz you are looping the query with for-each

Comment: can i use return false for the echo?